# Looking for a better way to plot data

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have data that describe several measurements taken from several individuals (each individual is represented by several measurements taken at several different time points).

I want to present the data as a scatter plot of measurements vs. individuals. Since for each individual I have several measurements, it means that I'll have a stack of points at each x-axis point.

Here's an example random code to generate these data:

```
  set.seed(1)
  n.individuals <- 10
  n.measurements <- 15
  vars <- runif(n.individuals, 0.1, 1)
  means <- runif(n.individuals, 1, 5)
  negative.idx <- sample(n.individuals, n.individuals/2)
  means[negative.idx] <- -1*means[negative.idx]
  df <- data.frame(measurement=c(sapply(1:n.individuals, function(x) rnorm(n.measurements, means[x], sqrt(vars[x])))),
                  individual=c(sapply(1:n.individuals, function(x) rep(x, n.measurements))))
```

Here's how I'm presenting the data so far:

```
  #add colors
  cols <- rgb(runif(n.measurements),runif(n.measurements),runif(n.measurements))
  df$col <- rep(cols, n.individuals)

  #simple plot
  plot(df$individual, df$measurement, col=df$col, lwd=2, xlab = "individual", ylab = "measurement")
  abline(h=0,lty=2)
  abline(v=seq(min(df$individual)-0.5, max(df$individual)+0.5, 1),lty=2)
```

[image]

I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to present the data (perhaps a ggplot way?)

Note that the signal I'm looking for in the data (and this is how I generated them) is that the measurements for each individual are correlated with respect to their sign. If they are uncorrelated with respect to their sign they should appear scattered on both sides of the y-axis.

Comment: Jitter, along with your own color code may be a good idea: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_jitter.html

Comment: Isn't this just a `?boxplot` essentially?

Comment: I guess a box plot with the points jittered and color coded should do it.

Comment: You don't need to jitter the points to use a boxplot, and the colors don't really look good. The simpler approach is `boxplot(measurement~individual, data=df)`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would jitter your individuals so that individual measurements do not overlap. Use this code:

```
plot(jitter(df$individual), df$measurement, col=df$col,
   lwd=2, xlab = "individual", ylab = "measurement")
```

There are a million ways to plot it in ggplot. Here's a quick violin graph:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(factor(individual), measurement))
p + geom_violin(aes(fill  = factor(individual))) + 
    geom_hline((aes(yintercept = 0))) + geom_jitter( ) + xlab("Individual")
```